# This git log output shows two branches as if they weren't branches? Please explain

Tags: git, git-log, git-history-graph

`feature/XY` is the name of a feature branch and is currently checked out. `feature/XY-refactor` is the name of another branch, that branched off of `feature/XY`.

When I run `git log --oneline`, I get the output below.
What does it mean that these two are right one after the other at the very top of the log output? I am using git bash on Windows.

```
user@host ~/Documents/repo (feature/XY)
$ git log --oneline
9feb11a (HEAD -> feature/XY, origin/feature/XY) Axis labels
d250b90 (feature/XY-refactor) Refactored
87d49c1 Fix typoe
6a8a7c7 Fix print statement
945ffca Fix code layout
3e747c9 Added spaces after comma
b143713 Changed fontsize
a669cd4 Commented out a print statement
// .. more commits
```

Comment: It means that the `feature/XY` branch (both in your local working copy and on `origin`) includes commits up to `9feb11a`, but your local `feature/XY-refactor` branch only includes commits up to `d250b90`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git log` will return all the commits reachable from a specific commit or set of commits (i.e. the history up to the specified commit(s)). When you don't specify a commit, it defaults to `HEAD`.

So you effectively ran `git log --oneline HEAD` which is equivalent to `git log --oneline feature/XY` (the checked out branch).

Thus your `git log` result is telling you that your `feature/XY` branch has as its parent (or one of its parents if `9feb11a` is a merge commit) the last commit of the `feature/XY-refactor` branch. In other words, the `feature/XY-refactor` branch has been merged into `feature/XY` one way or another.

`git log` shows a list of commits in chronological order but not their exact relationships. To see that use the `--graph` switch, which works especially well with `--oneline`:

```sh
git log --oneline --graph
```

For example, if `feature/XY-refactor` branched off at commit `3e747c9`, and was then merged with `feature/XY` before any separate work was done on `feature/XY` you would see the following:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph

* 9feb11a (HEAD -> feature/XY, origin/feature/XY) Axis labels
|\
| * d250b90 (feature/XY-refactor) Refactored
| * 87d49c1 Fix typoe
| * 6a8a7c7 Fix print statement
| * 945ffca Fix code layout
|/
* 3e747c9 Added spaces after comma
* b143713 Changed fontsize
* a669cd4 Commented out a print statement
// .. more commits
```

Or if `feature/XY` was rebased onto `feature/XY-refactor`, you would see the following:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph

* 9feb11a (HEAD -> feature/XY, origin/feature/XY) Axis labels
* d250b90 (feature/XY-refactor) Refactored
* 87d49c1 Fix typoe
* 6a8a7c7 Fix print statement
* 945ffca Fix code layout
* 3e747c9 Added spaces after comma
* b143713 Changed fontsize
* a669cd4 Commented out a print statement
// .. more commits
```

When you use `--graph`, it may reorder the commits to make a cleaner graph.

There is one flaw with `git log --graph`: It doesn't make it obvious when you have two or more separate commit histories that don't share a common root commit. But that is unlikely to be your case based on what you said.

Anyway, you can *always* see the history for any particular ref or "commitish" by giving it as an arg to `git log`. Try these commands:

```
git log --oneline --graph feature/XY
git log --oneline --graph feature/XY-refactor
git log --oneline --graph HEAD
git log --oneline --graph 6a8a7c7
```

If you want to see how two or more branches relate:

```
git log --oneline --graph <branch a> <branch b> ...
```

If you want to see ALL branches:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all
```

As a bonus, here's an even more detailed `git log` command, showing dates, times and author:

```sh
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Creset %Cgreen(%cd) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %C(red)%d%Creset %s' --all
```

Comment: then I wonder what `git log --oneline` by itself is useful for without the `--graph` option because the listed commits could be part of any of the branches

Comment: I added some more examples that partly answers your question. When you specify a commit (or a ref to a commit), it will show you all ancestor commits reachable from that commit. When you specify no commit, it will show ALL commits.  `git` is a power user's tool. It has elemental commands that can be combined to do many things. When you get more experience, it will make more sense.

Comment: Just added a bonus command at the end 

Comment: In this particular case, since the OP ran `git log --oneline` without additional starting points, we can tell that `d250b90` is the (or a) parent of `9feb11a`. So it's very likely just the case that `feature/XY-refactor` is exactly one commit behind `feature/XY`. Still, the `--graph` advice is good.

Comment: @torek, my bad, you are exactly right! I don't know what I was thinking... I totally know that by default `git log` === `git log HEAD`.   I just fixed my answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: @TMOTTM, my bad. See torek's comment and my reply and my update to the question. So your first comment above is spot on, and git actually behaves as you would expect, and NOT as I first described 